# A <div> that can increase/decrease its own height

Tags: css, html, height

I would like to create a `<div>` (called `div1` here) which expands its own height up to the limit of the browser's height (ie maximum height until it would produce an overflow with `scrollbar`):

```
<div id="div1"> </div>
<div id="div2">Bonjour </div>
```

Here is the css :

```
#div2 {
   height: 300px;
   background-color: #ccffcc;
}

#div1 {
   height: 80px; // what should I do here in order to maximize the height until overflow?
   background-color: #cc00cc;
}
```

**How to increase the height of div1 to maximum possible height?**

Here is a live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/XAjGM/2/.

Comment: What exactly is the question

Comment: make the `height: 100%`

Comment: Isn't there a CSS code in order to maximize a `div`'s height until overflow (I don't want scrollbars to appear!) ?

Comment: Does the `#div2` have to be a fixed height of `300px`?

Comment: Yes @AfromanJ fixed height for `#div2`

Comment: @AfromanJ, have you removed your answer? I cannot see it anymore

Comment: So you want both divs in the page and `div1` to take the space before the `div2` gets out of screen ?

Comment: Yeah sorry it was based on percentages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be your css so that you can achieve the desired.

```
html,body{
height:100%;
}

#div2 {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #ccffcc;
}

#div1 {
    height: calc(100% - 300px); //where 300px is the height of div2
   background-color: #cc00cc;
}
```

Comment: Can I use as well  `height: calc(100% - (#div2.height));` or something like this ?   Because in my real code #div2 may change auto

Comment: and with CSS only, is it possible ?

Comment: The `100%` in `#div2` is relative to what ? To the parent's height ?

Comment: we are giving height of the body as 100%. all the elements present in the body, when given height in percentage, will take body height as reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a wrapper element and use `display:table` on it and `display:table-row` on the `.div1` and `.div2` elements

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
.div1 {
    display: table-row;
    background: #cc00cc;
    height: 100%;
}
.div2 {
    display: table-row;
    background: #ccffcc;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="div1">
        contents of div 1
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        contents of div 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/55z22/

---

As you add content to `.div2` the `.div1` will shrink

Answer (score -1):

Try this 1:-

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;    
}

#div1 {
   height: 80px;
   background-color: #ccffcc;
}

#div2 {
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #cc00cc;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XAjGM/13/)

Comment: In you Fiddle @Anup, you can see a scrollbar, that was unwanted, do you know why it happened ?

Comment: ...doesn't this produce a scrollbar in your fiddle?